# Using separate data provider class with PHPUnit and attributes

Tags: php, attributes, phpunit

I would like to separate Tests and Data Providers. Using PHP 8 attributes, I cannot get the following test to run when referencing an external Data Provider:

```
#[Test]
#[DataProviderExternal(RouterDataProvider::class, 'registerGetRouteData')]
public function itRegistersGetRoute(Route $route, array $expectedResult)
{
    $this->router->get($route);
    $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $this->router->getRoutes());
}
```

My data provider class:

```
class RouterDataProvider
{
    public static function registerGetRouteData(): array
    {
        return [
            $route = new Route('/', ['IndexController', 'index']),
            [
                'GET' => [
                    '/' => $route,
                ],
                'POST' => []
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

How could I get this test to run with the desired provider method?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: @ChrisHaas unfortunately not, the test is just being skipped

Comment: If you remove the `DataProviderExternal` attribute does the test then run? It will obviously error out because of missing parameters, I just want to make sure PHPUnit can see it first.

Comment: @ChrisHaas the test runs without the DataProviderExternal attribute

Comment: Can you try making it not static? If that doesn't work, I'm unfortunately at a loss.

Comment: @ChrisHaas unfortunately changing it to a non-static method triggered a deprecation, however this did sort of help me solve the issue - I'll detail in an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running PHPUnit with the following flags, I was able to see exactly what my issue was:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --display-deprecations --display-warnings --diplay-errors --display-notices
```

The data set was invalid. Changing the `return` to `yield` and updating the return type for the `registerGetRouteData` method from `array` to `\Generator` resolved this.

I was running phpunit with the `--testdox` flag, so I'm not sure if this is what stopped me seeing any errors initially and assume the test was being skipped.